# A python question regarding guessing a random number, there's an error in my code

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have been tasked with writing a program that makes the computer generate a random number from 0-100, which the user has to guess.

This is my attempt:

```
import random
import math

x = random.randint(0, 100)
guess = int(input("Guess a number: "))
    if x == guess:
        print("You got the right number!!!")
 elif x > guess:
    print("The number you guessed was less than the actual number!")
 elif x < guess:
     print("The number you guessed was more than the actual number!")
```

I got an error when I tried running the code. How can I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/, and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. Did you try **reading** the error? Did you **understand** the error? Does your code actually look exactly as it appears in this post? (If so: do you understand what *indentation* is, and why it is important in a Python program?) I [edit]ed the question to [remove irrelevant conversation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343721) and **ask a question** explicitly; but there is still a lot missing here.

Comment: _I got an error when I tried running the code_ Are we supposed to guess what the error was?

Comment: `elif x > guess:\`enter code here\` ` . This looks like an editing problem rather than an issue with your actual code

Answer (score 1):

1. `if x == guess:` is not supposed to have an indent
2. The `math import` is unnecessary
3. The following code is not indented on the same level:

```
 elif x > guess:
    print("The number you guessed was less than the actual number!")
 elif x < guess:
     print("The number you guessed was more than the actual number!")
```

So it should be:

```
import random

x = random.randint(0, 100)
guess = int(input("Guess a number: "))
if x == guess:
    print("You got the right number!!!")
elif x > guess:
    print("The number you guessed was less than the actual number!")
elif x < guess:
    print("The number you guessed was more than the actual number!")
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and do not attempt to answer questions that are not well posed. It is OP's responsibility to attempt to locate problems before asking; this is not a debugging service. Questions that boil down to one or more typos are supposed to be closed and not answered; you can help by flagging (or at 3000+ reputation, voting to close).

Comment: `elif x > guess:\`enter code here\`` . This looks like an editing problem rather than an issue with OP's actual code

Answer (score 0):

If my assumptions are correct, it should be an error with the indenting.

In line 6, `if x == guess:` and line 8 `elif x > guess:`, they are on different indent levels.

Adjusting the `if` statement should fix the error, something like this:

```
import random
#import math    #not needed

x = random.randint(0, 100)
guess = int(input("Guess a number: "))
if x == guess:
    print("You got the right number!!!")
elif x > guess:
    print("The number you guessed was less than the actual number!")
elif x < guess:
    print("The number you guessed was more than the actual number!")
```

You need to make sure all the `if`s and `elif`s are on the same indent level for it to work.

Comment: Please read [answer] and do not attempt to answer questions that are not well posed. It is OP's responsibility to attempt to locate problems before asking; this is not a debugging service. Questions that boil down to one or more typos are supposed to be closed and not answered; you can help by flagging (or at 3000+ reputation, voting to close).